# Direct Sql or combine it in a procedure? which is more efficient

Tags: sql-server

in my recent subject ,I have to do some queries through dynamic SQL,But I'm curious about 
the efficiency in different ways:
**1)**combine the sql sentences in my server and then send them to the database ,do the query
**2)**send my variables to database and combine them in a certain procedure and finally do the query
Hope someone can help
BTW(I use .Net and Sqlserver)

Comment: If performance is important - try it and run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, one of the main things you should do is to parameterise your SQL - whether that be by wrapping it up as a stored procedure in the DB, or by creating the SQL statement in your application code and then firing the whole thing in to the DB. This will mean:

- prevention against SQL injection attacks by not directly concatenating user-entered values into a SQL statement
- execution plan reuse (subsequent executions of that query, regardless of parameter values, will be able to reuse the original execution plan) (NB. this could be done if not parameterised yourself, via [Forced Parameterisation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037.aspx))

Stored procedures do offer some extra advantages:

- security ,only need to grant EXECUTE permissions to the stored procedures, you don't need to grant the user direct access to underlying db tables
- maintainability, a change to a query does not involve an application code change, you can just change the sproc in the DB
- network traffic, not necessarily a major point but you're sending less over the wire especially if the query is pretty large/complex

Personally, I use stored procedures most of the time. Though the times I need to build up SQL dynamically in application code, it is always parameterised.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use stored procedure and pass parameters from your application, as Stored procedures are precompiled queries and have execution plan ready which saves lot of time.

You can refer this url which has details http://mukund.wordpress.com/2005/10/14/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-stored-procedure/

Happy coding!!

Comment: Dynamic SQL also has its execution plan cached. This is a common myth, debunked a long time ago. See http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/11/18/38178.aspx

Comment: This statement "as Stored procedures are precompiled queries and have execution plan ready which saves lot of time." is no longer true. Adhoc queries also have cached query plans